# Best way to organize / tile multiple windows on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to arrange Application Windows on Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/23769/how-to-arrange-application-windows-on-mac-os-x)

Often I find myself with 4 textmate windows open – e.g.:

[image]

Getting this to look right takes a lot of fiddling; what software can I use to automatically split the screen between these 4 windows?

Comment: Check this out at SO: [Tiling Window Manager for Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276760/tiling-window-manager-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

[MercuryMover](http://www.heliumfoot.com/mercurymover/) might be a good solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript solution:
http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=49916